# Laravel Request Class validate nested json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I need to validate nested JSON in Laravel Request class, how can I do this? This is my code

json request:

```
"formData" => "{"arrival_date":"2019-10-10","departure_date":"2019-10-10"}"
```

My FormRequest Validation Class:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'formData' => 'required|JSON',
        'formData.arrival_date' => 'required|string' // this not work
    ];
}
```